# Defining a Custom SQL Type in TypeORM for PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I'm utilizing TypeORM in my project, and I have a requirement to define a column with a custom SQL type, specifically ['datemultirange'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES) in PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, [TypeORM doesn't provide direct support for setting such a type](https://typeorm.io/entities#column-types-for-postgres). Are there any tools or workarounds available for achieving this?

Is there a method to specify a custom SQL type for a column in TypeORM that:

- ensures consideration during table creation.
- type checking when generating new migrations.

I would greatly appreciate any information on this matter. Thank you!

I try to find a way to set a custom type. Such a record is not supported:

```
@Column({ type: 'datemultirange' })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

If you want to set a type for a column that is not supported by TypeORM, you need to:

1. Go to the configuration and expand "**supportedDataTypes**":

   ```
   const dataSource = new typeorm.DataSource(defaultOptions);
   dataSource.driver.supportedDataTypes.push('datemultirange');
   ```
2. Set the required type in the metadata, in my case, it's "**datemultirange**"

   (TypeScript won't allow you to set it directly, so you'll have to disable type checking):

   ```
   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
   // @ts-ignore
   @Column({ type: 'datemultirange' })
   ranges: string;
   ```
3. Enjoy the new possibilities! =)